# Setting ColorField does not change colour of ScatterLineSeries in Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, radhtmlchart

I am trying to make a ScatterLineSeries to show up as a desired colour but they never set to the correct colour and Telerik just always uses its default colors to draw the markers and lines.  I've rewritten my code in two styles and neither have worked in getting the colours to change.  The data and labels are appearing as expected, it is just the colours that are not being set to the desired colours.

My code I have is here:

```
    <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="TimelineChart" Width="100%" Height="100%" PlotArea-XAxis-AxisCrossingValue="0" PlotArea-YAxis-AxisCrossingValue="0">
        <PlotArea>
             <Series>
                <telerik:ScatterLineSeries Name="Very High Risks" DataFieldX="Date" DataFieldY="vhr" MissingValues="Interpolate">
                    <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{1} Very High Vulnerabilities"></TooltipsAppearance>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>

               <telerik:ScatterLineSeries Name="High Risks" DataFieldX="Date" DataFieldY="hr" MissingValues="Interpolate" ColorField="Red">
                    <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{1} High Vulnerabilities"></TooltipsAppearance>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>

                <telerik:ScatterLineSeries Name="Medium Risks" DataFieldX="Date" DataFieldY="mr" MissingValues="Interpolate" ColorField="Orange">
                    <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{1} Medium Vulnerabilities"></TooltipsAppearance>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>

                <telerik:ScatterLineSeries Name="Low Risks" DataFieldX="Date" DataFieldY="mr" MissingValues="Interpolate" ColorField="Yellow">
                    <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{1} Low Vulnerabilities"></TooltipsAppearance>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>

                <telerik:ScatterLineSeries Name="Information Level" DataFieldX="Date" DataFieldY="info" MissingValues="Interpolate" ColorField="Green">
                    <TooltipsAppearance Color="White" DataFormatString="{1} Information Level Findings"></TooltipsAppearance>
                    <LabelsAppearance Visible="false">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </telerik:ScatterLineSeries>
            </Series>
            <XAxis BaseUnit="Days" AxisCrossingValue="0" Color="#b3b3b3" MajorTickType="Outside" MinorTickType="Outside" DataLabelsField="d" Type="Date">
                <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="0" DataFormatString="M/d/yyyy"></LabelsAppearance>
                <MajorGridLines Color="#EFEFEF"></MajorGridLines>
                <MinorGridLines Color="#F7F7F7"></MinorGridLines>
                <TitleAppearance Position="Center" Text="Date"></TitleAppearance>
            </XAxis>

            <YAxis Color="#b3b3b3" MajorTickSize="1" MajorTickType="Outside" MinValue="0"  MinorTickSize="1" MinorTickType="Outside">
                <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0}" RotationAngle="0"></LabelsAppearance>
                <MajorGridLines Color="#EFEFEF" Width="1"></MajorGridLines>
                <MinorGridLines Color="#F7F7F7" Width="1"></MinorGridLines>
                <TitleAppearance Position="Center" Text="Number of Items"></TitleAppearance>
             </YAxis>
        </PlotArea>

        <ChartTitle Text=""></ChartTitle>
        <Legend>
            <Appearance Position="Bottom"></Appearance>
        </Legend>
    </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

Here is a screenshot of the chart coming out with the wrong colours:

[image: Telerik Chart with wrong colours even though ColorField is set]

Any thoughts would be very appreciated.  I've searched everywhere to look for a solution and once again i did rewrite the code that I had before in order to have the colourfield set directly on the .aspx page, but it still did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the [Series Type].Appearance.FillStyle.BackgroundColor to change the colour of the line, and not use ColorField at all!

Comment: The answer was found here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-appearance-conditional-item-colirization.html

Comment: Or, if you have the colors in the data source, use the correct field name.